# UTC DATE in Sequelize.js

Tags: node.js, momentjs, sequelize.js

I'm using Sequelize in node.js to save open and close times. I'm also using moment.js to format. Alter a FindOrCreate I'm doing this:

```
result.open = moment(hours.open, "hh:mma").format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
result.save()
...
```

This works fine and the time gets formatted to MySQL's datetime format. The Problem is when I retrieve the time Seqquelize thinks it's a UTC time and converts it to EST (my server timezone).

I would prefer it to go into the database as UTC and come out the same way. Is there something I'm doing wrong? Why does Sequelize not convert it to UTC on insert but assumes it's UTC coming out? ALso, is there a way to not have it try to convert to my server timezone?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?  Im experiencing the same issue and I cant find any documentation on it.

Comment: @JeffRyan I don't know if my answer below is too later but I hope it fixes your issue if you're still having it (I HOPE NOT!) =)

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem.
i've fixed it like this:

`config/sequelize.js`:

```
const sequelize = new Sequelize(database, user, password, {
host,
dialect: 'mysql',
port,
operatorsAliases,
dialectOptions: {
    useUTC: true, // -->Add this line. for reading from database
},
timezone: '+02:00', // -->Add this line. for writing to database
pool: {
    max: 10,
    min: 0,
    idle: 10000,
},
logging: console.log,
// define: {},
})
```

momentJS (UTC):

```
const ACCEPT_FORMAT = 'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss'
const { start_date, end_date } = req.params
const start = moment.utc(start_date, ACCEPT_FORMAT)
const end = moment.utc(end_date, ACCEPT_FORMAT)
console.log(start)
console.log(end)
```

Hope it will help someone.... :)

Comment: Why `timezone: '+02:00'`? Isn't it meant to save in UTC?

Comment: @DavidA I am getting a warning that useUTC is an invalid option

Answer (score 7):

I know this is pretty late but here it is for those struggling with this with **postgres** (maybe this can point you in the right direction for other engines)

As you know postgres stores datetimes in UTC.

The issue, for me, turned out to be not in Sequelize but rather in the `pg` package.

In order to fix it, place this before your `sequelize = new Sequelize()` line

```
var types = require('pg').types;
var timestampOID = 1114;
types.setTypeParser(1114, function(stringValue) {
  return new Date( Date.parse(stringValue + "0000") );
});
```

The problem, I think, is that the `pg` package is doing `new Date(stringValue)`, which returns the date in the server's timezone, which is wrong (unless it's in utc itself)

For more info, please refer to this thread:
https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/issues/429

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same issue, you are using moment wrong.
You should use `moment.utc` instead of just `moment` .

Take a look at the moment documentation: http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/utc/

```
result.open = moment.utc(hours.open, "hh:mma").format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
result.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

Ist way.

go to data-types of mssql in node module

```
...\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\mssql\data-types.js
```

then modify your DateType value to your current utc like this

```
 class DATEONLY extends BaseTypes.DATEONLY {
    static parse(value) {
      return moment.utc(value).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
    }
  }
```

2nd Way(Recommended).

you can add useUTC property in Sequelize connection

```
const sequelize = new Sequelize({
    ......
    dialectOptions: {
        encrypt: false ,
        options: {
          useUTC: false, // for reading from database
          requestTimeout: 90000
        },
    },
    })
```

Comment: We need a solution that we can do outside dependencies (node_modules)

Comment: I have edited my solution and added 2nd way for permanent solution @Poode

Comment: Getting the following warning with `options`: `Ignoring invalid configuration option passed to Connection: options. This is currently a warning, but in future versions of MySQL2, an error will be thrown if you pass an invalid configuration option to a Connection` :(