# Can't save modified Date() obect to Sequelize DATE field

Tags: javascript, postgresql, datetime, sequelize.js

`user.addDays(3)` should set `user.expires` to +3 days from current time. However, it doesn't.

```
let User = sequelize.define('User', {
  email: DataTypes.STRING,
  name: DataTypes.STRING,
  expires: DataTypes.DATE
}, {
  instanceMethods: {
    addDays: function(days) {
      let date = this.expires ? this.expires : new Date()
      date.setTime(date.getTime() + days * 86400000)
      this.expires = date
      return this.save()
    }
  }
})
```

There are no save || validation errors, however user.expires is not modified. FYI, if I inspect `user` object before save, `expires` field is updated.

If I change:

```
this.expires = new Date()
```

`user.expires` changes to current date, so vanilla `Date()` object works.

It seems I'm missing something obvious.

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

**UPD:** According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17976459/utc-date-in-sequelize-js), it may be related to node-pg package. So, I should explicitly mention — I'm also using PostgreSQL.

**UPD #2:** For now, solved the problem with Moment.js:

```
addDays: function(days) {
  let date = this.expires? moment(this.expires) : moment()
  this.expires = date.add(days, 'days')
  return this.save()
}
```

It works. However, vanilla JS solution is still missing. I'm pretty sure, there's something wrong with Date format I'm supplying to PG. But no error is raised, that weird.

Clarification is still appreciated.