# new Date() changes hours problem _ JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I have this string date and I want to use it in a date type for querying in sequelize.

```
let date = "2019-08-08T12:53:56.811Z"
let startDate = new Date(date)
console.log(startDate)
->> 2019-08-07T12:53:56.811Z
```

when I am trying to insert to db.it changes with another hour.

```
let newTask = Task.create({ time_to_deliver: startDate})
console.log(newTask.time_to_deliver)
->> 2019-08-08 17:23:56
```

what is this? is it something about timezone and UTC time stuff?

Comment: Is `newTask.time_to_deliver` different date than `startDate.toLocaleString()`?

Comment: @barbsan yep you are correct . output startDate.toLocalString() is this :8/7/2019, 5:23:56 PM. but why? I did not tell sequelize store my date as to.localString()

Comment: Is `newTask.time_to_deliver` a Date object or a string?

Comment: According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48388996/7404943) you could use `dialectOptions: { useUTC: true },` option

Comment: @barbsan in the schema I defined time_to_deliver as DataTypes.Date. and I am inserting startDate in it . which represents let startDate = new Date(date)

Comment: @barbsan i passed useUTC option true in my sequelize connections. but same problem . task.time_to_deliver ->> 2019-08-07 17:23:56 . Iam so confused about this. your quess is correct . does not matter to sequelize what date Iam passing it turns to toLocalString() format .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197914/discussion-between-babak-abadkheir-and-barbsan).

Answer (score 1):

I think if you will make the "startDate" key in your DB of 'Date' type instead of 'String' type it will work. I have checked this with MongoDB and it worked for me.

```
"startDate: {type: Date}"
```

Answer (score 0):

you can simply use this javascript functions for better enhancement

```
var d = new Date("July 21, 1983 01:15:00");
var n = d.getDate(); //this will give you 21
```

there is also a similar function available - getMonth(),

First, get this date day and month and time [for the time you can use these functions => `1. getTime() and 2. new Date().toISOString()`]

and then send these things separately and combine them whenever you want retrieve.

**There is the also second approach;**

First, convert your date and time into a timestamp and enter that timestamp into the database.

```
var myDate="26-02-2012";
myDate=myDate.split("-");
var newDate=myDate[1]+"/"+myDate[0]+"/"+myDate[2];
alert(new Date(newDate).getTime());
```

Comment: Looking at the tags, OP is propably using PostgreSQL, not MySQL

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience, I didn't look there,

Answer (score 0):

according to @barbsan answer . sequelize changes the date to toLocalString() format. in querying return data it turns to the actual date.